# Is there a way to retrieve a delayed chat message programmatically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

as you know, MS Teams allows you to [schedule chat messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/schedule-chat-messages-in-microsoft-teams-2fc5ea77-7bb4-4511-8f59-e62bac1c0f6a?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5003350).
How can I list these deferred messages by code? MS GRAPH is preferable.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to list the scheduled messages. We only have this API endpoint in graph https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Comment: Currently there is no API for this scenario. You can suggest this feature at https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472.